# How to rotate a log4j log manually

Tags: java, rotation, log4j

I have log4j configured to rotate the log every day.

In special situations I would like to trigger an additional log rotation manually.

Is this possible - and if so: How?

**Solved like this:**

```
void rolloverLogs() {
    for(final Enumeration<?> loggers = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers(); loggers.hasMoreElements(); )  {

        final Logger logger = (Logger) loggers.nextElement();

        for (final Enumeration<?> appenders = logger.getAllAppenders(); appenders.hasMoreElements(); )  {

            final Appender a = (Appender) appenders.nextElement();

            if(!RollingFileAppender.class.isInstance(a))
                continue;

            ((RollingFileAppender)a).rollOver();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're keeping track of your appenders, you could call

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#rollOver()

That should do it. I guess it's also possible to iterate through all appenders you can find starting from root level - just make sure you keep track of which appenders you already rolled.

Answer (score 5):

The technique shown by Lahiru will only locate Appenders configured for a specific Logger which is based on the class the code resides in. The exact Appender(s) located may may vary if the configuration changes.

If you know the Appender name the best way to do this is:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext context = LogManager.getContext(false);
Appender appender = context.getConfiguration().getAppender(appenderName);
if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
    ((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager().rollover();
}
```

If you want to roll over all RollingFileAppenders you could do:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
for (Appender appender : context.getConfiguration().getAppenders().values()) {
    if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
        ((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager().rollover();
    }
}
```

Comment: +10.  Use similar code when using the RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Is above working for you. I believe rollover() is not available in log4j2 2.x versions. Do you know any workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

For log4j2, you can use following.

```
    org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logManagerLogger = LogManager.getLogger();
    Map<String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender> appenders = ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) logManagerLogger).getAppenders();
    appenders.forEach((appenderName, appender) -> {
        if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
            logger.info("Rolling over appender " + appenderName);
            ((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager().rollover();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get this message "The method rollover(RolloverStrategy) from the type RollingFileManager is not visible" when I use following method in log4j2. How to solve this or I believe rollover() is not available in log42 ?

Comment: @karan, please check whether `RollingFileAppender` you used belongs to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender` package.