# How to make a log file with only one line which is overwritten every time?

Tags: java, log4j2, overwrite

I'm using log4j2 (version 2.5) in Java 8.

I need a log file with only one line. Therefore for each writing, the previous line if it exists must be overwritten by the new line.

log4j.properties:

```
name=testLoggerOneLine
appenders=console, logFile

appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} 
[%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.logFile.type=File
appender.logFile.name=LOGFILE
appender.logFile.fileName=C:/Users/mggl/workspace/Test/logs/Test.log
#appender.logFile.immediateFlush=true
#appender.logFile.append=false
#appender.logFile.createOnDemand=false
appender.logFile.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.logFile.layout.pattern=%msg%n

loggers=logFile

logger.logFile.name=Test
logger.logFile.level=debug
logger.logFile.appenderRefs=logFile
logger.logFile.appenderRef.logFile.ref=LOGFILE
logger.logFile.additivity=false

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

Dummy code:

```
package Test.loggingTest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class OneLineLog
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("testLoggerOneLine");

        logger.info("first writing");

        logger.info("second writing");

        logger.info("third writing");
     }
}
```

In Test.log there must be written only the last logging info.

The option append with value false does the job for a bunch of logging information at each application start. I want to do the same for each line without restarting the application.

Any clue or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why?

Comment: It's a requirement. If it were me, I wouldn't make a log in this way.

Comment: Why would anyone require this? Btw, I don't know log4j, but a rotation of one line could be the solution.

Comment: A manual rotation worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using append and immediateFlush options (set to false and true respectively) in log4j.properties and forcing the rollover on the appender associated with the logger. I used the snippet written by rgoers in this discussion:
[How to rotate a log4j log manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996115/how-to-rotate-a-log4j-log-manually)

log4j.properties:

```
name=Test

appenders=console, logFile

appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} - %msg%n

appender.logFile.type=RollingFile
appender.logFile.name=LOGFILE
appender.logFile.fileName=.../logs/Test.log
appender.logFile.filePattern=.../logs/%d{yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}-Test.log.gz
appender.logFile.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.logFile.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}: %m%n
appender.logFile.policies.type=Policies
appender.logFile.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.logFile.policies.time.interval=1
appender.logFile.policies.time.modulate=true
appender.logFile.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.logFile.policies.size.size=500MB
appender.logFile.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.logFile.strategy.max=10
appender.logFile.append=false
appender.logFile.immediateFlush=true

loggers=logFile

logger.logFile.name=Test
logger.logFile.level=debug
logger.logFile.appenderRefs=logFile
logger.logFile.appenderRef.logFile.ref=LOGFILE
logger.logFile.additivity=false

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

Code:

```
package Test.loggingTest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration;

public class OneLineLog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Test");

        try {

            logger.info("first writing");

            LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
            AbstractConfiguration logConfig = (AbstractConfiguration) loggerContext.getConfiguration();
            Appender logAppender = logConfig.getAppender("LOGFILE");
            if (logAppender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
                RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = (RollingFileAppender) logAppender;
                rollingFileAppender.getManager().rollover();
            }

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            logger.info("second writing");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```